# How To Add Elements To a Dictionary?

Tags: python, tkinter

dam trying to make a phonebook project using python and Tkinter I need to add phone numbers to my phone book and i have written code for that but python throws out error.

```
from tkinter import*
#defining the submit button
def submit():
    new = entry2.get()
    new2 = entry3.get()
    my_dict.update({new:new2})

#definig the add button
def add():
top = Toplevel(root)
top.configure(background="black")
top.geometry("400x400")
top.title("Add new member")
label6 =Label(top,text="Welcome",bg="black",fg="orange")
label6.place(x=135,y=13)
global entry2
entry2 = Entry(top,width=23)
entry2.place(x=102,y=78)
label7 = Label(top,text="Name",bg="black",fg="orange")
label7.place(x=48,y=78)
global entry3
entry3 = Entry(top,width = 23)
entry3.place(x=108,y=127)
label8 = Label(top,text="phone number",bg ="black",fg="orange")
label8.place(x=0,y=129)
button3 = Button(top,text="Submit",command = submit)
button3.place(x=185,y=200)
#defining the chek button
def check():
global my_dict

my_dict = {"john":'7598769587'}
if entry.get() in my_dict: 
   label4 = Label(root,text=my_dict[entry.get()],bg="black",fg="orange").place(x=178,y=167)
   label5 = Label(root,text = entry.get()+" is :",bg ="black",fg = "orange").place(x=120,y=167)

   #creating the main window  
   root = Tk()
   root.title("vole phone book")
   root.geometry("400x400")
   root.configure(background="black")
   label = Label(root,text="phone book",bg="black",fg="orange",width=13).place(x=133,y=23)
   label2 = Label(root,text="Enter here.",bg = "black",fg="orange").place(x=2,y=89)
   entry = Entry(root,width = 27)
   entry.place(x=89,y=90)
   button =Button(root,text="Check",bg="yellow",fg="red",command=check).place(x=190,y=129)
   button2=Button(root,text="Add",width=23,command = add).place(x=120,y=300)

   root.mainloop()
```

This is my code and when i execute this

```
    my_dict.update({new:new2})
    NameError: name 'my_dict' is not defined
```

python shows the above error , What to do?

Comment: `some_dict['key'] = 'value'`. That said please fix your indention.

Comment: put the line `global my_dict` below `my_dict = {"john":'7598769587'}`

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: @RijilVarghese your code is a mess and it is hard to tell what is in what function. I can assume but we would rather you fix your indention.

Comment: @keksnicoh that doesn't work.

Comment: `if entry.get() in my_dict: ` will never be true so your code should never produce a root window.

Comment: Please do not try to guess and "fix" the indentation. The messed up indentation or what is (supposed to be) defined in which function may be an important part of the problem.

Comment: @KasemAlsharaa never correct someone else code indention. This will fix problems the OP needs to be aware of and correct on their own. By changing this you risk removing the reason for the code not working in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

While you use `global my_dict` when you define `my_dict` in `check`, it will still be only defined *after you call `check`*. And indeed, if you invoke `check` first, and then try to `add` a number, it works.

Define `my_dict` in the global scope, together with `root` etc., then it will work regardless of in which order the buttons are used.

```
my_dict = {"john":'7598769587'}
root = Tk()
...
```

(Then you can also remove the `global my_dict` from check as it will only read the variable.)

Comment: @RijilVarghese if this post solved your problem please select the green check mark next to the answer so this post can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set `my_dict` as global in your `submit()` function

```
def submit():
    global my_dict
    new = entry2.get()
    new2 = entry3.get()
    my_dict[new] = new2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working solution:**

```
# File name: phone-book-demo.py

from tkinter import*

# Define global phone book
global my_dict
my_dict = {"john":'7598769587'}

#defining the submit button
def submit():
    person = entry2.get()
    phone = entry3.get()
    my_dict.update({person:phone})
    print(my_dict)

#definig the add button
def add():
    top = Toplevel(root)
    top.configure(background="black")
    top.geometry("400x400")
    top.title("Add new member")
    label6 =Label(top,text="Welcome",bg="black",fg="orange")
    label6.place(x=135,y=13)

    global entry2
    entry2 = Entry(top,width=23)
    entry2.place(x=102,y=78)
    label7 = Label(top,text="Name",bg="black",fg="orange")
    label7.place(x=48,y=78)

    global entry3
    entry3 = Entry(top,width = 23) 
    entry3.place(x=108,y=127)
    label8 = Label(top,text="phone number",bg ="black",fg="orange")
    label8.place(x=0,y=129)
    button3 = Button(top,text="Submit",command = submit)
    button3.place(x=185,y=200)

#defining the chek button
def check():
    person = entry.get()
    if person in my_dict: 
        phone = my_dict.get(person)
        print("Found: " + person + " : " + phone)
        # Erase the old result by placing a blank label
        label0 = Label(root, width=200, bg ="black", fg = "black").place(x=10,y=167)
        label5 = Label(root, text = person + " : " + phone, bg ="black", fg = "orange").place(x=10,y=167)

#creating the main window  
root = Tk()
root.title("vole phone book")
root.geometry("400x400")
root.configure(background="black")
label = Label(root,text="phone book",bg="black",fg="orange",width=13).place(x=133,y=23)
label2 = Label(root,text="Enter here.",bg = "black",fg="orange").place(x=2,y=89)
entry = Entry(root,width = 27)
entry.place(x=89,y=90)
button =Button(root,text="Check",bg="yellow",fg="red",command=check).place(x=190,y=129)
button2=Button(root,text="Add",width=23,command = add).place(x=120,y=300)
root.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

```
$ python3 phone-book-demo.py 
Found: john : 7598769587
{'john': '7598769587', 'Alice': '123'}
{'john': '7598769587', 'Alice': '123', 'Bob': '777'}
Found: Alice : 123
Found: Bob : 777
```

**Screenshots of the phone book windows:**
[image: Screenshots of the phone book windows]

Comment: I would condense all your global's to a single line at the top of your function. There is no need to have global in multiple locations. IE `global entry2, entry3`